Convexity of functions on a Hilbert space
I am having some trouble finding a good reference on convex optimization on Hilbert spaces.
Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $f : H \to \mathbb{R}$.
If $f$ is twice differentiable for all $x\in H$ (denoting $D^2f(x)$ the bilinear form it induces), is there a link between the convexity of $f$ and the positive definiteness of $D^2 f$ ?
It seems that some results exist for quadratic forms, but I struggle to find precise definitions. For example, if $a$ is a bilinear form on $H$, is $v \mapsto a(v,v)$ a quadratic form ? What about $v \mapsto a(v,v) + a(v_0, v) + \langle v-v_1, v\rangle$, where $v_0$ and $v_1$ are elements of $H$ ? An what results exactly do we have on quadratic forms ?
My questions probably seem very confused (because I am at the moment quite confused :( ). If someone knows a solid clear reference on these questions I would be very grateful !
Thanks a lot !

There is no big difference between the theory for differentiable and convex function for finite- and infinite-dimensional spaces. In the infinite-dimensional case, one has to use Frechet derivatives. Then the characterizations of convexity by properties of first and second derivatives are the same as in the finite-dimensional case. No idea about references.
